# Passing data through open modal function Angular uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to pass `unit_number` into the modal when it pops up. I'm pretty new with Angular and I'm a little confused with what `resolve:` and `group:` are doing and how I can include the unit_number in that return statement.

```
    $scope.openTenantModal = function (unit_number) {
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/addtenantmodal.html',
    controller: 'AddTenantModalCtrl',
    size: 'large',
    resolve: {
      group: function () {
        return $scope.group;
      }
    }
  });
  modalInstance.result.then(function () {
  }, function () {
  });
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using ui-bootstrap

> Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS

To pass a variable to a modal's controller you need to use

```
resolve: {
   A: function() {
       return 'myVal'
   }
}
```

And then you can access that variable 'A' from the modal`s controller by injecting it

```
controller: ['A', function(A) {
    // now we can add the value to the scope and use it as we please...
    $scope.myVal = A;
}]
```

Check out: [https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

Resolve:

> Members that will be resolved and passed to the controller as locals; it is equivalent of the resolve property in the router.

And group is just a member (it could be anything you choose)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Took a little tweaking because our controllers are setup a little differently than standard, but got it to work. We have a lot of modals in our build so this will be very helpful moving forward.

Comment: Forgetting to inject it was my problem!

Answer (score 5):

Just add a property in resolve object `unitNumber` with a function returning `unit_number` value from it. So that you can get the `unit_number` value inside `AddTenantModalCtrl` by injecting `unitNumber` dependency in controller factory function.

```
resolve: {
  group: function () {
    return $scope.group;
  },
  unitNumber: function(){
    return unit_number
  }
}
```

> **Note**: Don't directly do `unitNumber: unit_number`, because when you have that, angular DI system will try to search the dependency
>   with name `unit_number`(value) and It will try to evaluate it as
>   function. Resultant you will get `$injector` error in console.